# Calling ASP.net webservice method with jQuery inline form validation Engine

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using **[jQuery inline form validation Engine](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/)** But unfortunately I dont know **why my web method does not hit**. I can see in fiddler that requess is sending to server but HTTP:500 error with that request.

Webservice Method:

```
[WebMethod]
public bool IsUserAvailable(string fieldId, string fieldValue, string extraData, string _)
{

    return true;
}
```

Rule:

```
 "ajaxUserCallAsp": {
                    "url": "Services/FWWebService.asmx/IsUserAvailable",
                    // you may want to pass extra data on the ajax call
                    "extraData": "name=eric",
                    // if you provide an "alertTextOk", it will show as a green prompt when the field validates
                    "alertTextOk": "* This username is available",
                    "alertText": "* This user is already taken",
                    "alertTextLoad": "* Validating, please wait"
                },
```

Fiddler Show Request Header:

> GET
>   /ForeverWords.Website/Services/FWWebService.asmx/IsUserAvailable?fieldId=Text1&fieldValue=sd&extraData=d&&_=1324507733538
>   HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 0):

This solved issue it is hitting now web method

```
<webServices>
    <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
    </protocols>
</webServices>
```